# Use np.loadtxt to split a column while reading

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, text-files, converters

Is there any way to use np.loadtxt and the converters argument to split a column into two columns?

The lines in my text file looks like this:

```
1 2 A=3;B=4
```

and I want to read this in as:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

The file is quite large so reading line by line will be too slow.

I tried this:

```
parse_col = lambda x: [ float(x.split(';')[0].split('=')[1]), int(x.split(';')[1].split('=')[1]) ]

np.loadtxt('demo.txt',usecols=[0,1,2],comments='#',converters={2:parse_col},dtype=int)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generator that calls a parser and pass it to `np.genfromtxt`:

```
import re

import numpy as np

def parser(s):
    for i in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', s):
        s = s.replace(i, '')
    return s.replace('=', '').replace(';',' ')

gen = (parser(line) for line in open('demo.txt'))
np.genfromtxt(gen, comments='#', usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3))
```

Note that I used `re.findall` to identify and replace a more general pattern, as pointed out by @PadraicCunningham.

Comment: This will only work for A and B which may not be all that is in the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you are right... I've updated the answer using `re.findall()` with a more general pattern

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thanks! Two issues -- I need to ignore columns (I do this in my parser function) and 'demo.txt' is a zipped file. Will this still work? I split s in 'parser' to choose columns and I am getting an indexerror

Comment: @Stefan check the edit I just did in the answer... there is a parameter `usecols` that you should use in order to ignore some columns... I think this is perfect for you case

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thanks, I was misunderstanding how the generator works -- I thought that usecols looks at the file and not the output of the generator. My input file was a bit more complex than this so I just replaced all '=' and ';' with '\t' and then did usecols to pick out the ones I was interested in. Thanks again!